# Yii2 move code from one pc's localhost to other pc's localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2

I am new to Yii2. I am using advanced template of Yii2.

I have code which works in one PC's localhost server, but when i copied it on other PC's localhost sever it gives me an `internal server` error.

.htaccess file in **advanced/ folder**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with admin first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advanced/(admin) 
RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/advanced/backend/web/(assets|css)/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)  
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advanced/(assets|css)  
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/advanced/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

.htaccess file in **advanced/backend/web/ folder**

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Is there anything wrong i have done? Please help..

Apache rewrite module is enables.

In php_error i found this:

```
[04-Jul-2015 09:00:50 UTC] An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The OpenSSL PHP extension is not installed.' in C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Security.php:480
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Security.php(503): yii\base\Security->generateRandomKey(32)
#1 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php(1292): yii\base\Security->generateRandomString()
#2 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php(1260): yii\web\Request->generateCsrfToken()
#3 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php(273): yii\web\Request->getCsrfToken()
#4 C:\wamp\www\advanced\frontend\views\layouts\main.php(20): yii\helpers\BaseHtml::csrfMetaTags()
#5 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(325): require('C:\\wamp\\www\\adv...')
#6 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(247): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\wamp\\www\\adv...', Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(386): yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\\wamp\\www\\adv...', Array, Object(frontend\controllers\SiteController))
#8 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(372): yii\base\Controller->renderContent('<div class="sit...')
#9 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorAction.php(108): yii\base\Controller->render('error', Array)
#10 [internal function]: yii\web\ErrorAction->run()
#11 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Action.php(92): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(151): yii\base\Action->runWithParams(Array)
#13 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#14 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(80): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#15 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(101): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#16 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#17 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not found.' in C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:187
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(75): yii\web\Request->resolve()
#1 C:\wamp\www\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(common\components\Request))
#2 C:\wamp\www\advanced\frontend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
$_SERVER = [
    'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'localhost',
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate',
    'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'PHPSESSID=6p7cjhqhskro8632hccfmcn1l6',
    'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive',
    'PATH' => 'C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\Skype\\Phone\\;',
    'SystemRoot' => 'C:\\Windows',
    'COMSPEC' => 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
    'PATHEXT' => '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC',
    'WINDIR' => 'C:\\Windows',
    'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '',
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.4.42',
    'SERVER_NAME' => 'localhost',
    'SERVER_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1',
    'SERVER_PORT' => '80',
    'REMOTE_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1',
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => 'C:/wamp/www/',
    'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'admin@localhost',
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => 'C:/wamp/www/advanced/frontend/web/index.php',
    'REMOTE_PORT' => '51416',
    'REDIRECT_URL' => '/advanced/admin/site/login',
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
    'QUERY_STRING' => '',
    'REQUEST_URI' => '/advanced/admin/site/login',
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/advanced/frontend/web/index.php',
    'PHP_SELF' => '/advanced/frontend/web/index.php',
    'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1436000450.7279999256134033203125,
    'REQUEST_TIME' => 1436000450,
]
```

Comment: please help me as soon as possible

Comment: If the server tells the browser that there is an internal server error, then you need to look in the server logs to find out what that error is.

Comment: where i can find it on local sever?

Comment: I have no idea where your server is configured to store its log files.

Comment: it is on wamp server

Comment: Add this in the start of you index.php     "error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
    defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');" and see error in browser

Comment: i am working on localhost

Comment: @PavelBariev what i have to add?

Comment: @PavelBariev still same

Comment: should i install some yii2 or anything?

Comment: @PavelBariev it is telling this: `The OpenSSL PHP extension is not installed.`

Comment: Here we go! Now you've got too Google and fix every error message.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown because the server you are running this application at doesn't have Linux's /dev/urandom or /dev/random and OpenSSL PHP extension is not installed.

You said it's WAMP server so left click wamp tray icon, go to PHP > PHP extensions > make sure php_openssl is checked - if not check it and restart.